# Regarding Combining Two Small Javascript Codes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically the question is self explanitory.  I can't figure out how to combine small snippets of javascript rather than having two separate files.

The two codes are :

```
$(function(){
    $('.navbar li').each(function(){
      if(window.location.href.indexOf($(this).find('a:first').attr('href'))>-1)
        {
      $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});

$(function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu li').each(function(){
      if(window.location.href.indexOf($(this).find('a:first').attr('href'))>-1)
        {
      $(this).removeClass('active')
        }
    });
});
```

Another question, is the first `$(function()` necessary?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.navbar li, .dropdown-menu li').each(function(){
      if(window.location.href.indexOf($(this).find('a:first').attr('href'))>-1)
        {
            if($(this).parents(".navbar").length > 0)//this is to figure out if we are working with LI inside .navbar or not.
                $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            else
                $(this).removeClass('active')

        }
    });
});
```

Functions are almost equal, except that you need to detect if you are working with LI from .navbar or not to select corect `removeClass` code.

Also, in your code first `$(function()` is necessary. Otherwise code inside it could be started before document is loaded. But you may put both pieces of code inside one `$(function()`

Answer (score 1):

#### You can do this way:

Create a function and call it under it. Or, you do this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.navbar li').each(function(){
      if(window.location.href.indexOf($(this).find('a:first').attr('href'))>-1)
        {
      $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        }
    });
    $('.dropdown-menu li').each(function(){
      if(window.location.href.indexOf($(this).find('a:first').attr('href'))>-1)
        {
      $(this).removeClass('active')
        }
    });
});
```

Some notes:

1. Those two functions are different.
2. You don't need the two function starters, `$(function(){})` twice.

Answer (score 0):

Full working sample, this will make the first LI of first UL red, and remove the red from the second ul LI. Your two functions are now combined.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
        .active {background-color:red}
        ul.dropdown-menu>li.active {background-color:red}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
    <ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/cisadohe/Desktop/new10.htm">first</a></li>
    <li>old</li>
    <li>new</li>
    <li>4</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="file:///C:/Users/cisadohe/Desktop/new10.htm">first</a></li>
    <li>old</li>
    <li>new</li>
    <li>4</li>
    </ul>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.navbar li').each(function(){
          if(window.location.href.indexOf($(this).find('a:first').attr('href'))>-1)
            {
          $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            }
        });

        $('.dropdown-menu li').each(function(){
          if(window.location.href.indexOf($(this).find('a:first').attr('href'))>-1)
            {
          $(this).removeClass('active')
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    </html>
```